# How to console.log numbers from array instead of strings

Tags: javascript

Heres my code

`var ns =['Kyle', 'Mods',1,2,3];
console.log(ns);`

So i dont want the strings be logged i only want the numbers from the array how?

Comment: If you know the range of integers you could also use slice on array -
 console.log(ns.slice(2,5));

Answer (score 2):

```js
var ns =['Kyle', 'Mods',1,2,3];
ns.forEach((element) => {
if(!isNaN(element)) {
 console.log(element)
}
})
```

Checkfor each element is number or not

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```js
    var ns =['Kyle', 'Mods',1,2,3];

    
    ns.forEach(function(ele){
    
    if (Number.isInteger(ele))
    console.log(ele);
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var ns =['Kyle', 'Mods',1,2,3];

console.log(ns.filter(x=> !isNaN(x) ));
```

Comment: OOOOO Filter block

Answer (score 0):

#### [ES6 Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable)

```
var ns =['Kyle', 'Mods',1,2,3];
var [ , , ...numbers] = ns;
console.log(numbers);
```

And the `...` is [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays).